# Trouble with special characters in index titles

Tags: indexing, tocbibind

I am a French student writing with LaTeX. I have a use for multiple index with different names for which I use `splitidx`. I wanted my indices to appear in the TOC, so I used `tocbibind`. Everything worked fine but with an accent in one of my index title I get a error message relating to encoding. Here is a MWE (well not working might be more accurate !). Have you got any idea of how I could politely ask `tocbibind` to expand correctly the indices title in the toc file ?

Thanks a lot.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\newindex[Index des journaux et séries]{jo}
\newindex[Index des noms de personnes]{np}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Ici du texte avec des accents qui fonctionne : é, à ç, è. Une indexation pour jo\sindex[jo]{phenix@Phenix} et une pour np\sindex[np]{phenix@Phenix}.

\printindex[jo]
\printindex[np] 

\end{document}
```

I think I see where the problem lies. If I try a chapter with an accent it get written `\IeC {\'e}` in the toc file whereas my index title always keeps its é even if I put the \IeC {\'e} in the text.

Comment: Try to use a `\protect{}` around your text with special characters

Comment: I tried, without any success so far. I still got "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char \u8:éri not set up for use with LaTeX ...chapter}{Index des journaux et {séries}}{2}"

Comment: Wild try: use `\usepackage[french]{babel}`

Comment: It was in my original document, I took it out from the MWE because it had no effect whatsoever on this specific problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the usage of `\xdef` in `\newindex`, which should be `\protected@xdef`; with `\xdef` almost any accented character in the index title will produce the error. The `tocbibind` package is not involved in the issue.

It's a bug that should be fixed by the package author.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[makeindex]{splitidx}
\usepackage{xpatch}
% let's use \protected@xdef instead of \xdef in \newindex
\makeatletter
% there are four occurrences
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\xpatchcmd{\newindex}{\xdef}{\protected@xdef}{}{}
\makeatother

\usepackage{tocbibind}
\newindex[Index des journaux et séries]{jo}
\newindex[Index des noms de personnes]{np}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Ici du texte avec des accents qui fonctionne : é, à ç, è. Une indexation pour 
jo\sindex[jo]{phenix@Phenix} et une pour np\sindex[np]{phenix@Phenix}.

\printindex[jo]
\printindex[np]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, I do feel a little less stupid. I just changed the package but it's good to know where the problem lies.

Comment: @Chicordine I believe you should file a bug report to the author of `splitidx`.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't stick to `splitindex` try `imakeidx` instead, the syntax is similar and there are no errors about special characters, at least not in this example.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[makeindex]{splitindex}
\usepackage[splitindex]{imakeidx}%
\usepackage{tocbibind}
%\newindex[Index des journaux et séries]{jo}
%\newindex[Index des noms de personnes]{np}

\makeindex[name=jo,title={Index des journaux et séries}]
\makeindex[name=np,title={Index des noms de personnes}]
\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

Ici du texte avec des accents qui fonctionne : é, à ç, è. Une indexation pour jo\index[jo]{phenix@Phenix} et une pour np\index[np]{phenix@Phenix}.

\index[jo]{é@letter é}


\printindex[jo]
\printindex[np] 

\end{document}
```

I randomly put some index entry there, without direct conjunction to the right place `;-)`

[image]

Comment: Oh, for some reason I was going to give the same exact answer. `;-)`

Comment: @egreg: I could hardly imagine why `;-)`

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I did not know about this package. It works just fine now.